# Как правильно оформлять python проекты для git'a?

Tags: python, git, github

Как правильно оформить python проект для дальнейшего использования другими людьми? Как составлять список зависимостей для быстой установки окружения? Какие правила по заполнению readme есть?

Comment: Заполнить setup.py, собрать whl-пакет и залить на PyPI

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. На каждый из вопросов в вопросе есть куча статей в интернете

Comment: Так, чтобы работала команда `git-buildpackage`.